# Python selenium change only part of current url after each loop

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a question regarding a script that I am writing. The problem is indicated in: `#FIXME` comment,`start_string` should be inserted only once but it kept inserting after each iteration.

script.py:

```
NUMBER_OF_PAGES_TO_SEARCH = 50 #change this if you want to go over more pages

page = NUMBER_OF_PAGES_TO_SEARCH

start_string = '&start='
while True:
    if page != 0 :
        try:
            #FIXME: start_string is inserted after each loop, page decrement is working correctly

            driver.get(driver.current_url + start_string +str(page))
        except:
            break
        
        time.sleep(7)
            
    # print(page_to_count)
    page = page - 10
    if page == 0:
        break

    print(page)
```

Comment: You mean, after each **iteration** of a loop the `start_string` is inserted?
Please post the whole `for` loop so we can see what you are iterating over.

Comment: @xcoding Please share all of your code..and the error.

Comment: Just use a for loop instead of while

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to execute the start_string only once? and then only change the page number? Then we can use a boolean flag.
Initialize the `flag=False` before the while loop, and use if-else inside your try block, something like this :

```
if (not flag):
     driver.get(driver.current_url + start_string +str(page))    
else:
     driver.get(driver.current_url +str(page))
flag=True
```

This code will execute the `driver.get(driver.current_url + start_string +str(page))` only once and then it will keep executing the else block.

Comment: tried this but i only got (current url) and decremented numbers, no (start_string)

Comment: As you mentioned in the question that "looking for a way to keep start_string from not inserting each time", so i thought you want start_string to be inserted only once, so exactly what output are you expecting here?

Comment: output expected should be : (current_url&start=50), once loop restarted (50 will be decremented to 40) etc, but not (current_url&start=50l&start=40) etc

Comment: managed to insert start_string once, but got another problem, when &start=50, inserted, the decremented number not changing instead this is the url output &start=504030 etc..

Answer (score 0):

your use of a while loop is just outputting the same result as is inputted. try instead a `for` loop so the code doesn't automatically insert its self every time it runs through.